# xcopy text file adds space to data - CMD Batch File

Tags: batch-file, cmd, xcopy

I have a text file where I need to delete the first line of data every now and then.  I have a batch script that does this for me, but for some reason it adds a space to the end of each line of data.

After many loops, this grows the data file greatly (10k+ lines of data getting a space with every xcopy) and I am trying to figure out have to copy the lines of data as is without adding the extra space at the end.

Here is my script:

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=*" %%a in (C:\Users\User1\Documents\DataSources\AccountData.csv) do (
    echo %%a >>C:\Users\User1\Documents\DataSources\newfile.txt    
)

xcopy C:\Users\User1\Documents\DataSources\newfile.txt C:\Users\User\Documents\DataSources\AccountData.csv /y

del C:\Users\User1\Documents\iMacros\DataSources\newfile.txt /f /q
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks a bunch!

Chris

Comment: what if you removed the space between %%a and the >> operator?

Comment: @dlatikay, is correct.  You are physically echoing a space to the file. Which compo has corrected with his answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick way is to change it to:

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=*" %%a in (C:\Users\User1\Documents\DataSources\AccountData.csv) do (
    (echo %%a)>>C:\Users\User1\Documents\DataSources\newfile.txt    
)

xcopy C:\Users\User1\Documents\DataSources\newfile.txt C:\Users\User\Documents\DataSources\AccountData.csv /y

del C:\Users\User1\Documents\iMacros\DataSources\newfile.txt /f /q
```

Comment: yes. it may be worth adding a line or two for why this makes a difference

Comment: @dlatikay, because just removing the space between %%a and the >> operator is not the solution.

Comment: @dlatikay, removing the space in theory does fix the problem but there is a gotcha involved.  If your data ends in a number, the batch file will think you are redirecting to a different file stream.  So to fix that issue you enclose the command in parentheses.